# Maven/Gradle way to calculate the total size of a dependency with all its transitive dependencies included

Tags: maven, gradle, pom.xml, dependency-management

I would like to be able to perform an analysis on each of my project POMs to determine how many bytes each direct dependency introduces to the resulting package based on the sum of all of its transitive dependencies.

For example, if dependency A brings in B, C, and D, I would like to be able to see a summary showing A -> total size = (A + B + C + D).

Is there an existing Maven or Gradle way to determine this information?

Comment: If C brings in C1 and C2, you want those included as well I suppose?

Comment: Yes, the intent is to be able to easily identify the impact of a dependency on the total size of the resulting WAR or executable JAR.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I keep the a small `pom.xml` template on my workstation to identify **heavy-weight** dependencies.

Assuming you want to see the weight of *org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client* with all of its transitives create this in a new folder.

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>not-used</groupId>
  <artifactId>fat</artifactId>
  <version>standalone</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
      <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
           <phase>package</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
           </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then `cd` to the folder and run `mvn package` and check the size of the generated fat jar. On Unix-like systems you can use `du -h target/fat-standalone.jar` for that.

In order to test another maven artifact just change `groupId:artifactId` in the above template.

Comment: Thanks, that is the closest thing that I've found as an answer.  I still can't believe that there isn't a proper (built-in) way to do this.

Comment: There is no built-in way I'm aware of as of Jan 2016. [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) is the closest which could have been be helpful, but unfortunately `mvn dependency:get` has deprecated downloading into a custom location; `mvn dependency:copy` doesn't support transitive dependencies and `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` requires a `pom.xml` file which makes it **at least** as cumbersome as the solution above.

Answer (score 19):

Here's a task for your build.gradle:

```
task depsize  {
    doLast {
        final formatStr = "%,10.2f"
        final conf = configurations.default
        final size = conf.collect { it.length() / (1024 * 1024) }.sum()
        final out = new StringBuffer()
        out << 'Total dependencies size:'.padRight(45)
        out << "${String.format(formatStr, size)} Mb\n\n"
        conf.sort { -it.length() }
            .each {
                out << "${it.name}".padRight(45)
                out << "${String.format(formatStr, (it.length() / 1024))} kb\n"
            }
        println(out)
    }
}
```

The task prints out sum of all dependencies and prints them out with size in kb, sorted by size desc.

Update: latest version of task can be found on [github gist](https://gist.github.com/medvedev/968119d7786966d9ed4442ae17aca279)

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks! :) Anyway to display this in a similar way to 'gradle dependencies'?

Comment: No idea. However, you can enjoy updated revision of task. Now it contains padding and output looks even more awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any way to show the totals but you may get a report for your project which can show per dependency size information. Please check this maven plugin : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for as I can already get this info just by opening the resulting war file.  Still, thanks for pointing this plug-in out as it does have some nice features like the license summary.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a configuration which includes all the necessary dependencies that you wish to calculate the size for you can simply put the following snippet in your build.gradle file:

```
def size = 0
configurations.myConfiguration.files.each { file ->
    size += file.size()
}
println "Dependencies size: $size bytes"
```

This should print out when you run any gradle task after the build file is compiled.

Comment: `No such property: size for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated
Possible solutions: state, name`