# Identify large size dependencies in a fat jar created using maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a fat jar created using maven 3.5.

I am trying to reduce the size of fat jar. Can someone let me know how I can determine the size of the larger dependencies? If a dependency A brings in B & C . Then the size of A should be the sum of the size of A, B & C.

Is there a way to do this in maven 3.5?

Comment: Maybe use `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` and look at individual jar sizes under `target\dependency`. Then use `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out how dependencies are imported

Comment: This answer can help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35094282/369946 The question is the same like yours. But it forces you to do it for each dependency

Comment: Shouldn't you analyse which dependencies you need and which not? What does it help you to know the largest dependency if you need that dependency?

Comment: @JFabianMeier In my case, I could challenge the need for that dependency and either (only) code what I need or use alternative lighter dependency. Or not, but at least I'd like to know

Comment: @Daniele I know it's old but you should make that an answer. It's actually very practical